Добавить объект DocumentFragment в разметку
let sp = new DocumentFragment()
...
this.m.innerHTML = '';
this.m.append(sp);

Так собираю все созданные объекты в одну переменную, затем собранный список необходимо добавить в html разметку. Но сперва необходимо почистить блок, чтобы сработала анимация.
Собственно вопрос, как возможно сразу объекты добавить в блок, в замен тем что есть. В данный момент, приходится сперва почистить блок, затем только добавить

this.m.replaceChildren(sp);
